# Word-wrap doesn't work in "Simple-Marquee" Newsticker (joomla! plugin)

Tags: html, css, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I'm using the plugin "Simple Marquee" for Joomla 3.x.

I just want the text to automatically break when it reaches the div border. You can test it here: On the left hand site click on the link "Administrator" and type in "demo" for username and password:
http://marqueeticker.demo.mediahof.com/de/

I used the right newsticker as an example. My newsticker text ist the following:

```html
<div align="center" style="width: 10px; height:350px;">
  <p style="height:350px; overflow-wrap: word-break !important;">Demon str hj jh atio asf as fasd fas dfasdf asd fasd fwaf waefaw fewef wefawaef waef awefawefawefwaefawefwafwaefawefwefweafwa efn image</p>
  <p>
    <img src="/images/powered_by.png" alt="" width="165" />
  </p>
</div>
```

I set the width of the div. I tried with `word-wrap: break-word;` and `overflow-wrap: break-word`. I tried to put these attributes in the div as well as in the p-tag itself. Nothing works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: should be `overflow-wrap: break-word;` not `overflow-wrap: word-break` or `word-break: break-all;`

Comment: Thanks for replying and correcting. Have you tried it? It still doesn't work.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2kzr3Ld3/

Comment: I know it should work in "normal" condition. I was actually referring to the plugin: http://marqueeticker.demo.mediahof.com/de/